# Solaris' stdlib.h functions implemented by C++ libs?

Tags: c++, solaris

I am struggling with a port of an open-source tool to Solaris. Most things work, cmake/pkg-config/etc. are there, dependencies are found, gmake works, compiler and linker calls look all fine and tren, boom:

```
Undefined           first referenced
 symbol                 in file
std::qsort(void*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int (*)(const void*, const void*))      ...
```

This part I don't understand. At the first glance, std::qsort does not make sense, it is supposed to be part of C library, not STL. So I looked into stdlib.h and found a list of things like `using std::sort;` and dozens of other standard functions like `free`, `malloc`, `atoi`, etc., redirected in case of C++ context.

What is Oracle doing there and why? Which library am I supposed to link with if they do redirect it like this? Or why does CC command not pull that in automatically like GCC does?
I tried adding -lstdc++ but no luck.

Alternatively, the plain libc versions seem to be defined in <iso/stdlib_c99.h> (or <iso/stdlib_iso.h>). Is it legal to include one of those headers directly or will this wreak other random havoc at link time?

Edit:

since there are multiple suspicions of the build system weirdness, here is the basically the linking call from the gmake execution:

```
/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/CC -std=c++11 -xO3 -DNDEBUG <i.e. bunch of object files> -o ../systest  -L/opt/csw/lib/64 -lintl
```

I cannot see anything special there and I expect CC to figure out what to link to get the obligatory functionality.

Comment: The real question is: how on Earth do you build this so that the standard libraries are not linked to the binary by default? That's the part I don't understand, unless cmake is simply broken on Solaris. The linker should automatically link your application with the C and C++ runtime libraries. If it doesn't, something's funky. The redirections you speak of are interesting but of no importance here - they are baked into the standards (well, the redirections aren't, just the existence of the related symbols, and who would implement such pairs twice - nobody, 'cuz it's silly - thus redirections).

Comment: No, the real question is: who is responsible for the key part in the process? Let me break it down: a) C++ compiler, b) calling user, and if (b) then b1) get the lib name from the manpage? or b2) find it from somewhere else? or b3) cmake/autoconf shall figure it out? or b4) user check code for cmake/autoconf shall figure it out?

And regarding sense: it seems like Sun/Oracle implement the code twice anyway, in C runtime and in C++ runtime. This part does not make sense. Unless user shall be able to link cpp apps without libc, only cpp runtime.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica The compiler command posted will produce a 32-bit binary.  But the `-L` option indicates **64-bit** libraries are being searched.  That problem must be fixed, and since we don't know what's in `/opt/csw/lib/64` we don't know what libraries are failing to load.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is that `#include <xxx.h>` puts names into the global namespace and is allowed to also put them in `std`. Conversely, `#include <cxxx>` puts names into `std` and is allowed to also put them into the global namespace. In practice, this means that there are two approaches to implementing the functions from the standard C library in C++: declare the standard C library names in the `<xxx.h>` headers and hoist those declarations into `std` in the `cxxx` headers, or declare the names in `std` in the  headers and hoist those declarations into the global namespace in the `<xxx.h>` headers. With the former approach, the name of the function will be `qsort`; with the latter, it will be `std::qsort`. Either way, that error message usually indicates a setup problem with the compiler. The linker isn’t finding the standard library.

Comment: The linker is invoked by CC, the C++ compiler (C++! Not C). And then it should instrument the linker correctly to include the correct C++ runtime library. But apparently this does not happen. How is the user supposed to fix or work around this? I cannot find any documentation to solve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

This compile command

```
/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/CC -std=c++11 -xO3 -DNDEBUG ...
```

will produce a 32-bit executable.  Per [the Oracle `CC` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E54439/uc-cc-1.html#scrolltoc):

> On Oracle Solaris, `-m32` is the default. On Linux systems supporting 64-bit programs, `-m64 -xarch=sse2` is the default.

But this library option

```
-L/opt/csw/lib/64
```

is searching a directory full of **64-bit** libraries.

Either add `-m64` to the compile command or use the 32-bit library path.

**Update**

The question almost certainly would be answerable had it included the full error message, which is almost certainly something like this:

```
CC -g qsort.cc -o qsort
"qsort.cc", line 15: Error: Could not find a match for std::qsort(int[4], unsigned, unsigned, int(void*,void*)) needed in main(int, char**).
"/usr/include/iso/stdlib_iso.h", line 184: Note: Candidate 'std::qsort(void*, unsigned, unsigned, extern "C" int(*)(const void*,const void*))' is not viable: argument '4' can't be converted from 'int(void*,void*)' to 'extern "C" int(*)(const void*,const void*)'.
"/usr/include/iso/stdlib_iso.h", line 187: Note: Candidate 'std::qsort(void*, unsigned, unsigned, int(*)(const void*,const void*))' is not viable: argument '4' can't be converted from 'int(void*,void*)' to 'int(*)(const void*,const void*)'.
```

This code works just fine when compiled with Oracle Developer Studio 12.6 on Solaris 11.4:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    int i1 = *( ( int * ) p1 );
    int i2 = *( ( int * ) p2 );
    return( i1 - i2 );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int array[ 4 ] = { 5, 8, 12, 4 };

    qsort( array, sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[ 0 ] ),
        sizeof( array[ 0 ] ), &compare );
}
```

Comment: Your hint is the first going into some useful direction. However, it gets worse when I try to fix it. Even a simple repro like this fails:
`#include <errno.h> #include <limits.h> #include <stdarg.h>` and build this like `/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/CC -c repro.cc -std=c++11 -m64 -I/usr/include` and the result is: `"/usr/include/sys/va_impl.h", line 98: Error: Only one of a set of overloaded functions can be extern "C".` . I am now seriously disgusted by the Oracle toolchain and going to try clang next.

Comment: @PasterOfMuppets You shouldn't need `-I/usr/include`.  Oracle's C++ compiler is quite a bit more pedantic about adherence to the C++ standard than GCC is.  You might need to use `#include <cstdarg>` instead, for example.  Or you might need to patch your system if it's not up-to-date.

Comment: @PasterOfMuppets Note that even the original 2004 version of `va_impl.h` forked from Solaris [in the OpenSolaris source code](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate) has comments on line 98.  If your system has not been updated or patched, you're likely trying to do the equivalent of using GCC 9 to do a C++11 compile, **but on 15-to-20-year-old RHEL 2**.

Comment: Not up-to-date? Something from 2004? Seriously? Sorry, this is a few weeks old VirtualBox image from the Oracle server (version 11.4) and I installed the latest Oracle Studio, following the latest download instructions. It's not my fault if Oracle delivers crappy old headers. It's also not my fault if the compiler is inept to grok the inclusion of very basic C headers. And since when am I obliged to include C++ wrapper headers instead of  C versions? You are blaming the victim here.

Comment: @PasterOfMuppets You're no victim.  The compiler presented you with a full error message with a lot of information that you failed to post.  I'd bet the function you're passing to `qsort()` is `int compare( void *, void * )` instead of the required `int compare( const void *, const void * )`.

Comment: Wrong. A) what your bet does not make sense WRT the error message, and the comparer signature passed to it is actually:
`static int ocompare(const void *p1, const void *p2)`
The only explanation I can imagine is that static makes the symbol not exported to qsort - but then again, why does the compiler do that since it knows that the function is accessed by pointer right in the same compilation unit.

Comment: @PasterOfMuppets So it took you two-and-a-half months to note that the function is actually declared/defined as `static`?  (C functions do **not** have "signatures" - that word appears **nowhere** in [the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)...)  If other compilers are allowing compilation units other than the one that contains the `static` C function to link to that function, [**those compilers are broken**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2p3).  The entire purpose of `static` when applied to a file-scope identifier is to **prevent** such linkage.

Comment: As said before, I am stuck at the va_impl.h bug now. Still the same situation, BS message
`"/usr/include/sys/va_impl.h", line 98: Error: Only one of a set of overloaded functions can be extern "C".` and that's all, no hint about what it believes to be the forbidden overload.
And you imply that I use an ancient version, while I told that I simply installed the latest stuff by the book. `uname -a ->
SunOS sunshine 5.11 11.4.0.15.0 i86pc i386 i86pc
`
So if you are right and the Oracle delivers ancient file versionst hen you can see the degree of motivation to touch this %§"& in those months.